# Using files and data in Python

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Can we store images, audio and video or other files like PDF in any dictionary or files in Python? How can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Read it as raw binary data and Python will not care.

```
with open("/path/to/file.foo", "rb") as file_descriptor1:
    file_content_bytes = file_descriptor1.read()
# The "with" block will close the file descriptor for you

my_dictionary = { "file.foo": file_content_bytes }
```

See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

And see: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects